# svg while dual building with vite and webpack

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vite

For the short run, I need to maintain both webpack and vite builds as we convert from vue 2/webpack to vue 3/vite. Otherwise we will never be able to find the time to make the move to vite.

I've found ways to get around a lot of the differences so that the code is the same for both. I'm stuck on this, though. I'm importing an svg for including inline.

In vue 2/webpack I do this:

```
import myimage from "!rawloader!@/assets/icons/myimage.svg"
```

In vue 3/vite I do this:

```
import myimage from "@/assets/icons/myimage.svg?raw"
```

It works if I add `?raw` to the webpack version, so what I'd like to do is be able to have `!rawloader!` in the vite version and have vite ignore it. Is that possible?

My first thought was to put a define in vite.config.ts like this:

```
define: {
  '!rawloader!': '',
}
```

But that gives me the error:

```
✘ [ERROR] The define key "!rawloader!" must be a valid identifier

✘ [ERROR] Invalid define value (must be valid JSON syntax or a single identifier):
```

Is there a way to tell vite to just filter out a particular string completely by text replacement?

Alternately, is there a way to load the svg in webpack without `!rawloader!`?

Comment: Did you try `alias` in vite.config -> resolve?

Comment: Yes! That worked. If you make that an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define an alias in `vite.config.js`:

```js
export default defineConfig({
    ...
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            "!rawloader!": ''
        }
    }
})
```